# Sharing and updating data among laravel components

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10

i have a laravel layout and a page with 5 components. i am sharing a array to my page. i want to add some data in that array in component files and after that i want to access them in my layout file

I have tried by passing variable using view()->share('data',[])

Comment: Your question is not clear to me, Are you passing an array to your view file to serve those components? Isn't that array accessible in parent view that you are extending from?

Comment: i have defined a variable suppose ($component_name=[]). I want to append component name from each component and access after all component included. Think as i want to display list of components i have included.